# Allowing Object or null in jMock expectations

Tags: java, junit, jmock

I recently upgraded from jMock 2.5.1 to 2.6.0, and it seems that some of its dependencies have changed, causing some of my previously passing tests to fail.

One of my tests has the following expectation that used for the common setup of several tests:

`oneOf(service).event(with(any(Long.class)));`

In my test suite, `event` gets called with both `null` and valid `Long` values.  This used to be perfectly acceptable in jMock 2.5.1, but after the upgrade, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected invocation: service.event(null)
expectations:
  expected once, never invoked: service.event(an instance of java.lang.Long)
what happened before this:
  locator.locateService()
  service.getService()
at org.jmock.api.ExpectationError.unexpected(ExpectationError.java:23)
at org.jmock.internal.InvocationDispatcher.dispatch(InvocationDispatcher.java:85)
at org.jmock.Mockery.dispatch(Mockery.java:231)
at org.jmock.Mockery.access$100(Mockery.java:29)
at org.jmock.Mockery$MockObject.invoke(Mockery.java:271)
at org.jmock.internal.InvocationDiverter.invoke(InvocationDiverter.java:27)
at org.jmock.internal.FakeObjectMethods.invoke(FakeObjectMethods.java:38)
at org.jmock.lib.concurrent.Synchroniser.synchroniseInvocation(Synchroniser.java:82)
at org.jmock.lib.concurrent.Synchroniser.access$000(Synchroniser.java:23)
at org.jmock.lib.concurrent.Synchroniser$1.invoke(Synchroniser.java:74)
at org.jmock.lib.JavaReflectionImposteriser$1.invoke(JavaReflectionImposteriser.java:33)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.system(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I suspect this might be due to the new version of Hamcrest that jMock 2.6.0 uses, but I'm unsure.  Is there a more suitable matcher I can use to specify both null and non-null values for this method?

Answer (score 6):

After doing a bit more research, I learned this is a [known change in functionality](https://github.com/jmock-developers/jmock-library/issues/64) from jMock 2.5 -> 2.6.

The workaround I discovered is to use `with.is(anything())`, which matches null and non-null values.

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking too long for how to do this. For me the syntax was `(Long) with(anything())` though.